# Как понять это выражение в c++? (typedef, указатели на функции)

Tags: c++, c

```
typedef int (*SIG_TYP)(int);
typedef void (SIG_ARG_TYP)(int);
SIG_TYP signal(int, SIG_ARG_TYP);
```

Наткнулся на этот пример кода в книге Бьерна Страуструпа "Язык программирования c++". Первая и вторая строки кода мне понятны. Но что делает третья строка? Как ее понимать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не выражение, а объявление. Третья строка - это обыкновенное объявление (прототип) функции по имени `signal`. Тип возвращаемого значения - `SIG_TYP`.

В нем нет ничего необычного, кроме разве что типа аргумента `SIG_ARG_TYP`. Это функциональный тип, который в контексте параметра функции будет автоматически заменен на тип "указатель на функцию" `SIG_ARG_TYP *`

---

P.S. Есть обоснованные подозрения, что либо вы криво воспроизвели вторую строчку, либо в книге опечатка. Ошибки здесь нет, но наличие "лишних" скобок вокруг `SIG_ARG_TYP` как бы намекает на то, что автор намеревался написать

```
typedef void (*SIG_ARG_TYP)(int);
```

В оригинале именно так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И тип возвращаемого значения в обоих случаях `void`.

Comment: Хм... Действительно. Спасибо за ответ. Я читаю русскую версию, так как мой английский еще недостаточно хорош для прочтения оригинала (я над этим работаю). И в русской версии код именно такой, какой в самом вопросе, я прям с pdf файла скопировал его.